# JTable no se muestra en mi Jframe en java Swing!

Tags: java, java-swing, jtable

Amigos, un gusto saludarlos espero y se encuentren de lo mejor estoy teniendo un problema al visualizar mi componente `JTable` cuando cargo ejecuto mi proyecto no se logra apreciar la tabla, miren este mi codigo:

```
JTable miTabla1 = new JTable(modelo);
    JScrollPane miBarra = new JScrollPane(miTabla1);


this.getContentPane().add(jButtonContinuar, null);
        //this.getContentPane().add(miTabla1, null);
        this.getContentPane().add(miBarra, null);

        //add(miBarra);
        miBarra.setBounds(100, 300, 379, 130);
        miBarra.setVisible(true);
        miTabla1.setVisible(true);

DefaultTableModel modelo= (DefaultTableModel)miTabla1.getModel();
```

Anexo codigo donde formo la tabla y extraigo la información:

```
private void construirTabla(){

        String data [][]={};    
        String col[]={"TIPO EVENTO SIC","TIPO DERECHO COVACK",
                        "ES_REGIMEN_FISCAL","ORIGEN_DERECHO", 
                        "NOTAS"};
        modelo = new DefaultTableModel(data, col);//Ejemplo video


        //miTabla1.setModel(model);

        //Revisa y modifica estos metodos
        //String informacion[][]=obtenerMatriz();ojo
        //miTabla1 = new JTable(informacion,titulos);ojo


        //miTabla1 = new JTable(informacion,titulos);


        //miBarra.setViewportView(miTabla1);
    }



private void agregarValores(JSONObject json){   
        int cont = 0;
        //if(modelo==null){
            //miTabla1.setModel(modelo);    
            //System.out.println("ttttttttttttttttt");
        //}


        DefaultTableModel modelo= (DefaultTableModel)miTabla1.getModel();   //Aqui marca error  

         Vector row = new Vector();

            modelo.insertRow(0, new Object[]{});            
            System.out.println("uuuuuuuuuuuuu..."+modelo);  
        //Captura de valores Json
            JSONObject retencion = (JSONObject)json.get("retencion");
            JSONObject importeNeto = (JSONObject)json.get("importeNeto");
              row.add(json.get("transaccion"));
              row.add(json.get("fechaPago"));
              row.add(json.get("creditoDebito"));
              row.add(retencion.get("percent"));
              row.add(importeNeto.get("amount"));


            /*modelo.setValueAt(json.get("transaccion"), cont, 0);
            modelo.setValueAt(json.get("fechaPago"), cont, 1);

            modelo.setValueAt(json.get("creditoDebito"), cont, 2);
            modelo.setValueAt(retencion.get("percent"), cont, 3);
            modelo.setValueAt(importeNeto.get("amount"), cont, 4);*/

            //modelo.setValueAt("0", cont, 0);
            cont++;     
            //Hasta aca
            miTabla1.setModel(modelo);
    }



private void obtenerMatriz() {//JJ Metodo con el que estoy trabajando

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        try{
            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader ("D:/Usuarios/JBustamante/Desktop/C0_2019-05-31_927837_0.json"));

            System.out.println("Cadena completa json del archivo..." + obj);

            JSONObject jsonObjectArchivo = (JSONObject)obj;//se guarda en la variable jsonObject la cadena json del archivo
            Object objJson = jsonObjectArchivo.get("opciones");
            if(objJson instanceof JSONArray){
                System.out.println("Esto es un array de opciones"); 
                JSONArray obj2 =  (JSONArray)objJson;           
                System.out.println("Objsss...."+ obj2);
                //Recorremos en array, ya que sabemos su tamaño  

                for(int i = 0; i< obj2.size();i++){ //Recorrido de transacciones           
                    JSONObject elementoItem =(JSONObject) obj2.get(i);
                    JSONArray transacciones = (JSONArray)(elementoItem.get("transacciones"));
                    for(int j = 0; j< transacciones.size();j++){
                        JSONObject transaccionesItem =(JSONObject)transacciones.get(j);
                        agregarValores(transaccionesItem);
                    } 
                }

            }          

        }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Dentro del cuadro gris es donde quiero que se muestre mi `JTable` pero nomas no se muestra, por favor indiquen me que es lo que estoy haciendo mal por favor o si me falta algo que ponerle díganmelo, ya que con otros componentes como poner un botón si me lo hace, quedo al pendiente de sus comentarios y si me hace falta que no quede entendido con gusto lo pongo, saludos.

[image: +]

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema está en que el modelo que usa la tabla no tiene definición de columnas.

Tu código indica como modelo la variable `modelo`, pero tiene un par de problemas el cómo lo haces (o por lo menos como nos lo muestras):

1 - La variable `modelo` está definida debajo de la línea que la utiliza durante la creación del objeto de tipo `JTable` (quizás esta variable la tienes definida en otra parte del código y la agregaste solamente para mostrar como es su definición, pero de ser así no queda claro que sea lo estás indicando). Esto provocará un error de compilación ya que en este punto no existirá dicha variable.

2 - Aunque subas el código de la línea donde defines la variable `modelo` arriba de donde creas el objeto de tipo `JTable` seguirás teniendo el mismo problema, ya que lo único que haces aquí es tomar el modelo que por defecto tiene la tabla y reasignárselo. Esto no tiene ningún efecto.

Para solucionar estos problemas y que la tabla se visualice correctamente debes crear un modelo que tenga una definición de columnas. Por ejemplo:

```
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new String[] {"Columna 1", "Columna 2"}, 0);        
    jTable.setModel(model);
```

Este código indica que la tabla tendrá 2 columnas cuyos encabezados serán "Columna 1" y "Columna 2"; y que inicialmente no tendrá filas (0).

En tu código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
    // Crear el modelo con definición de columnas 
    DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel(new String[] {"Columna 1", "Columna 2"}, 0); 

    JTable miTabla1 = new JTable(modelo);
    JScrollPane miBarra = new JScrollPane(miTabla1);

    this.getContentPane().add(jButtonContinuar, null);
    //this.getContentPane().add(miTabla1, null);
    this.getContentPane().add(miBarra, null);

    //add(miBarra);
    miBarra.setBounds(100, 300, 379, 130);
    miBarra.setVisible(true);
    miTabla1.setVisible(true);
```

**Actualización por edición de la pregunta**

El nuevo código que agregaste correspondiente al método `construirTabla()` debería funcionar para la creación de un modelo para tu tabla y que al agregárselo muestra las columnas correctamente. Solo debes asegurarte de llamar a este método antes de esta línea: `JTable miTabla1 = new JTable(modelo);`.

*Nota*: Asumo que la variable `modelo` pertenece a la clase.

El código quearía así:

```
    // Crear el modelo con definición de columnas 
    construirTabla()

    JTable miTabla1 = new JTable(modelo);
    JScrollPane miBarra = new JScrollPane(miTabla1);

    this.getContentPane().add(jButtonContinuar, null);
    //this.getContentPane().add(miTabla1, null);
    this.getContentPane().add(miBarra, null);

    //add(miBarra);
    miBarra.setBounds(100, 300, 379, 130);
    miBarra.setVisible(true);
    miTabla1.setVisible(true);
```

Respecto al método `agregarValores(JSONObject)` te puedo decir que debes modificar esta línea: `modelo.insertRow(0, new Object[]{});` para utilizar el vector donde agregas los valores de cada columna con los datos, ya que al no utilizarlo se muestra una fila vacía. Otra cosa importante es que debes siempre llamar al método `insertRow()` después que el arreglo o vector ya tenga datos, sino se mostrará la fila vacía. También sobran las líneas donde obtienes la referencia al modelo de la tabla, puesto que este es una variable de la clase, y donde le reasignas a la tabla su mismo modelo.

```
private void agregarValores(JSONObject json) {   
    int cont = 0;

     Vector row = new Vector();

     //Captura de valores Json
     JSONObject retencion = (JSONObject)json.get("retencion");
     JSONObject importeNeto = (JSONObject)json.get("importeNeto");
     row.add(json.get("transaccion"));
     row.add(json.get("fechaPago"));
     row.add(json.get("creditoDebito"));
     row.add(retencion.get("percent"));
     row.add(importeNeto.get("amount"));

     modelo.insertRow(0, row); 

     cont++;
}
```

Comment: Hola, ya se encuentra un método donde jalo la información, volveré a editar mi pregunta y pondré el método

Comment: Hola E. Betanzos Ya edité mi pregunta

Comment: Hola @cratus666jose, por favor trata de agregar el código de manera que podamos ver de que modo llamas a al método `construirTabla()` porque estoy completamente seguro que lo que está ocurriendo es que el modelo de la tabla no tiene definición de columnas. Si usas el modelo que creas dentro de este método tiene que funcionar.

Comment: Hola amigo, una disculpa ya que si se me pasó ponerlo, pero si estoy teniendo complicaciones para solucionarlo, podría ser similar a la solución que me brindas ya teniendo en cuenta los métodos que anexé y si es así como podría comenzar para corregir este problema? Quedo al pendiente de alguna duda o comentario, que tengas un excelente día :)

Comment: @cratus666jose, acabo de editar la respuesta para que veas cómo debe quedar con tu mismo código, el cual debe decirte que probé y funciona perfectamente con dichos ajustes. Saludos

Comment: Hola buenas tardes, perfecto deja y lo acoplo a mi codigo muchas gracias :)